# how to transition between pygame windows and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

UPDATED CODE:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 700
height = 700
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dijkstra's Path-Finding Algorithm Solver")
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

def title_main():
    title_font = pygame.font.Font('TrajanPro-Regular.otf', 40)
    text_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 30, bold=True)
    Dijkstra_img = pygame.image.load('Dijkstra.jpg')
    text1_display = title_font.render("Dijkstra's Path-Finding", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text2_display = title_font.render('Algorithm', True, (255, 255, 255))
    text3_display = text_font.render('Press any key to continue...', True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Dijkstra_img, (225, 40))
    screen.blit(text1_display, (75, 400))
    screen.blit(text2_display, (225, 460))
    screen.blit(text3_display, (190, 550))

def title_game():
    title_font = pygame.font.Font('TrajanPro-Regular.otf', 35)
    title_display = title_font.render('Dijkstra Path-Finding Algorithm', True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(title_display, (12, 15))

def title_underline():
    rect = pygame.Rect(0, 60, 800, 3)
    rect_display = pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 255, 255], rect)
    title_font = pygame.font.Font('TrajanPro-Regular.otf', 100)
    title_display = title_font.render('', True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(title_display, (270, 198))

def grid():
    grid_x = 0
    grid_y = 63
    blockSize = 20
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blockSize + grid_x, y*blockSize + grid_y, blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,200,200), rect, 1)

def game_loop():
     game_is_active = True
     while game_is_active:
         for game_event in pygame.event.get():
            if game_event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_is_active = False
            if game_event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                start = print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                print(start)
         screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
         title_game()
         title_underline()
         grid()
         pygame.display.update()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        title_main()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            running = game_loop()
        pygame.display.update()
```

I have created a title page for my project under a function that I run when I start the GUI, but what I want to do is that when the user presses any key, I want to NOT display the title_main() function anymore and just display my main application instead. I used KEYDOWN to try to do this but for some reason, its very slow and non-responsive and also the title_main() function still is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cribber explains why your existing loop is not working.

I would like to provide an answer where only a single event-loop is used because I believe having a simple main-loop is the best architecture for an event-driven program (i.e.: all PyGame programs).

Your program is divided into two states, showing the "title page" and "main application".  I would keep this state in a variable, and determine which path to take in the main loop based on it.  At each step of the *draw → input → update cycle*, examine the state (iff necessary) and act based on the value.

```
# Function definitions as per question

# States the app can be in
TITLE_PAGE = 10   # TODO: maybe use an Enumerated Type
MAIN_APP   = 20

app_state = TITLE_PAGE  # start with the titles

while running:
    # Handle user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if ( app_state == TITLE_PAGE ):
                # user dismissed title page, switch to app-mode
                app_state = MAIN_APP

    # Update the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if ( app_state == TITLE_PAGE ):   # In Title-page mode?
        title_main()
    elif ( app_state == MAIN_APP ):   # In Main-Application mode?
        title_game()
        title_underline()
        grid()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Sure, when it's very simple like this, it's not a big deal which way it's implemented.  But as the program becomes more and more complex, it helps to lay-out the logic flow in simple steps.  There's no *duplicated* event-loop code blocks, or screen-painting, so (for example) if there's a user-input bug, it can only be in one place.

**EDIT: Handling first and second mouse clicks**

It's pretty easy to handle two mouse clicks.  It's just necessary to remember both the click-count, and where the "previous" click was.

This can be accomplished by storing a single initialised variable `first_click`, but starting with a value of `None`.  The None is important, because it indicates there has not been a click yet.  So it tracks the first/second click, and where the position of the first click.

So...

- if `first_click == None` → User has not clicked yet
- if `first_click != None` → First click OK, waiting on second.

In your code, `first_click` is called `start`.  It just needs to be initialised to None.

```
start = None   # no clicks yet

def game_loop():
     game_is_active = True
     while game_is_active:
         for game_event in pygame.event.get():
            if game_event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_is_active = False
            if game_event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Mouse has been clicked
                if ( start == None ):             # Is this a first click?
                    # Save the First click 
                    start = pygame.mouse.get_pos()      
                else:
                    # This is a second click, process both
                    handleTwoClicks( start, pygame.mouse.get_pos() )
                    # reset back to no-clicks-made
                    start = None
```

Comment: I see! My question is how I would go about checking the MOUSEDOWN twice? Assuming that I want the user to enter a starting and an ending point? Also when I am printing the mouse position I get the position and also None. I am not too sure as to how I can fix this. I have edited my code above to the new code which I have currently.

Comment: @JackJones - With the MOUSDOWN event, it also send the mouse position in `event.pos`.  Create a `last_mouse_position = None`.  When receiving the MOUSEDOWN event, If in `MAIN_APP` mode, store `event.pos` into `last_mouse_position` IF `last_mouse_position` is None.  If it's not None, then this is the 2nd mouse press - so handle the line.  after that reset `last_mouse_position` back to None.

Comment: okay so I understand the solution but the problem which I had when I did this method was that the position of the mouse which I got when I did event.pos was the same position the mouse was clicked. how can I make it so that I check for a NEW mousedown and then store that event.pos into another variable for example. To be more specific I am referring to the (- so handle the line) part.

Answer (score 2):

The lines in the block beneath `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` only get executed if a button is pressed - and only once per KEYDOWN!

Since you have no separate loop after the initial pygame.KEYDOWN, your `while running:` continues after the functions `title_game()`, `title_underline()` and `grid()` are executed once. Then the loop starts anew and the function `title_main()` also gets executed again (which is why it is still displayed).

I think you might want to implement another loop after the KEYDOWN was registered.

You will also have to capture the input in this loop separately as you don't "come back" to the `for event in pygame.event.get():` in your `while running:` loop.

I included a bit more cleaned-up version of the code and implemented a game loop after showing your `title_main()` as I understood your problem.

```
while running:  # your loop - display the title and wait for a button to be pressed
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        title_main()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
              # start the actual game upon pressing a button for the first time
              running = game_loop() # stop the loop if the game returns with False
        pygame.display.update()
    

def game_loop():
     game_is_active = True
     while game_is_active :
         for game_event in pygame.event.get():
            if game_event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  return False  # return to your outer loop
         # game logic - display the title, the underline and the grid: 
         screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
         title_game()
         title_underline()
         grid()
         pygame.display.update() # update screen
```

Comment: alright, this makes perfect sense and it also works, the question I have now is how I can check if the mouse is pressed twice instead of once (the first click representing the start point and the second click representing the endpoint). Also I have updated my code above and for some odd reason when I print the mouse position, it prints the mouse x,y coordinates but under it, prints None for some reason.

Comment: As Kingsley points out, it probably is caused by having two event-loops beneath each other. I didnt test my code with the entirety of your initial code, but wanted to give pointers as to how to solve your initial problem. Kingsley's solution below is better refactored and cleaner than mine if you continue developing.